# Math equations in Objective C iOS development

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I am trying to develop a starter app just to get used to some of the utilities of Xcode and iOS development. I am trying to create an app that will solve the quadratic equation. I have tried to add this code under the "Calculate " button action. First I had "Calculate" just add the three inputs together. Now I am trying to make it solve the equation. This is what I put so far.

```
-(IBAction) Calculate {

float x = ([A.text floatValue]);  
float y = ([B.text floatValue]);
float z = ([C.text floatValue]);

total.text =[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%.2f", -y+sqrtf(y*y-4*x*z)/2*x;

}
```

I know this is not the full equation, but this is what I have so far. The error I receive is to add a bracket where the semicolon is. How to make this more effecient? I wanted to create a `solveEquation()` function but I ran into problems. What can I do?

Comment: Also, mind your [order of operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) on that quadratic equation.

Answer (score 3):

You need more brackets!

```
total.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%.2f", -y+sqrtf(y*y-4*x*z)/2*x];
```

The brackets indicate that you're sending an Objective-C message.  For each message you send, you'll need one pair of brackets.  Let's break it down like this:

```
NSString *uninitializedString = [NSString alloc];
NSString *initializedString = [uninitializedString initWithFormat:@"%.2f", x+y+z];
total.text = initializedString;
```

In the first line, we send the `alloc` message to the `NSString` object, which is actually a *class* object that knows how to allocate instances of `NSString`.  But it does *not* initialize the instances.  It pretty much just allocates the memory for them.

In the second line, we send a message to this allocated-but-uninitialized instance of `NSString`, telling it to initialize itself by formatting the template `%.2f`.  This message returns an initialized instance of `NSString`.

Finally, in the third line, we use that initialized instance of `NSString`.

Obviously, it would be tedious to always need an intermediate variable to hold an allocated-but-not-initialized object.  So we eliminate it by taking the result of the first message, and sending a message directly to it:

```
total.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", x+y+z];
```

Comment: I’ll also add, errors like this are much easier to see with simpler format strings. You might consider setting some variable to `-y+sqrtf(y*y-4*x*z)/2*x` then using that in `initWithFormat:` so that you can parse it a little easier.

Comment: Thank you so much. Ya'll really helped me. I appreciate everyones expertise!!

Answer (score 3):

You need more brackets. The correct syntax is `[object message]`, and since `[NSString alloc]` returns an object, you need `[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", -y+sqrtf(y*y-4*x*z)/2*x]` (`initWithFormat:` being another message).